# How to set consumes and produces of rest controller in mockmvc using Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have a controller like this;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(GA)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GaController {

    private final GaService service;

    @PostMapping(value = INITIALIZE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<GaDTO> initialize() {
        return status(CREATED).body(service.initialize());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = FIND, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<GaDTO> find(@PathVariable String id) {
        return ok().body(service.find(id));
    }

    @PutMapping(value = PLAY, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<GaDTO> play(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) {
        return ok().body(service.play(request));
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return status(NO_CONTENT).build();
    }

}
```

And in my unit test, I used `@WebMvcTest` and `@MockMvc` but I don't know how to set `produces` and `consumes` configurations in `mockMvc`.

Here's an example;

```
@Test
public void initialize_success() throws Exception {
    when(gaService.initialize()).thenReturn(gaDTO);

    mockMvc.perform(post(GA + INITIALIZE)
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(gaDTO.getId())));
}
```

Is this true? I mean, `.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)` refers to `produces` or `consumes`?

Comment: I don't think you need to define it in your test class. It is already done in your controller.

Comment: Hi @Abdu,

Ideally it should work with contentType in MockMvc test. If it is not working then you can think of passing the accept header as well.
We are doing as below in our project for MockMvc based Junit.
            mockMvc.perform(
                post(BASE_URL)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
Try once like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the case for SpringBoot, but with JPA you should have the Annotations @Consumes and @Produces which you can put above a method.

For example you can put @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
or @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

given that MediaType is available as well.